# HP ProLiant Gen8 Health Agents and EL6.x - cpqHoMibHealthStatusArray has changed to the value: x

Tags: monitoring, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, snmp

I've noticed that my HP ProLiant Gen8 servers report the following message via email to root (or the destination configured in `/opt/hp/hp-snmp-agents/cma.conf`) upon restart.

```
Trap-ID=11020

cpqHoMibHealthStatusArray has changed to the value :02 03 02 02 02 02 02 03 02 02 02 02 02 01 01 02
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

or sometimes...

```
Trap-ID=11020

cpqHoMibHealthStatusArray has changed to the value :02 04 02 02 00 00 02 04 02 02 02 02 02 01 01 02
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This seems to be unique to the EL6.x and Gen8 combination and happens upon initial boot or the restart of the `hp-snmp-agents` service. Any ideas on what this output means?

Comment: As position 7 has failed it looks like it is indicating that the log is full, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented.  Check out the post at HP Blogs called "[HP ProLiant Gen8 Agentless Management Overview](http://h30507.www3.hp.com/t5/Coffee-Coaching-HP-and-Microsoft/HP-ProLiant-Gen8-Agentless-Management-Overview/ba-p/108579)" -- the relevant portion is copied below.  Basically, each array element is the status of a different monitored component.

The definition of “cpqHoMibHealthStatusArray”:

```
  cpqHoMibHealthStatusArray OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX  OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..256))
      ACCESS  read-only
      STATUS  mandatory
      DESCRIPTION
         "The MIB Health Status Array is an array of status values representing an
            overall status in element 0 follwed by server and storage status values as follows:

           Octet   Element   Field
          ======== ======= =========
             0        0    Aggregated Status of array elements
             1        1    Status of element 1
             2        2    Status of element 2
             .
             .
             .
             n        n    Status of element n


          Status         0 - Not available
                         1 - Other
                         2 - OK
                         3 - Degraded
                         4 - Failed
             .
             .
    Mibs are assigned an array element as follows.  New items are added at the end.
         0 -  System Health Status (overall status as reported by who is reporting (agents or iLO))
         1 -  Total Aggregate (Includes IML Status)
         2 -  Processors    (TBD 232.1.2.2.4:cpqSeCpuCondition)
         3 -  Memory        (232.6.2.14.4:cpqHeResilientMemCondition)
         4 -  Cooling       (232.6.2.6.4:cpqHeThermalSystemFanStatus)
         5 -  Sensors       (232.6.2.6.3:cpqHeThermalTempStatus)
         6 -  Power         (232.6.2.9.1:cpqHeFltTolPwrSupplyCondition)
         7 -  ProLiant Logs (232.6.2.11.2:cpqHeEventLogCondition)
         8 -  ASR           (232.6.2.5.17:cpqHeAsrCondition)
         9 -  Drive Array   (232.3.1.3:cpqDaMibCondition)
         10 - SCSI          (232.5.1.3:cpqScsiMibCondition)
         11 - Storage Enclosures (232.8.1.3:cpqSsMibCondition)
         12 - IDE           (232.14.1.3:cpqIdeMibCondition)
         13 - FC            (232.16.1.3:cpqFcaMibCondition)
         14 - Networks      (232.18.1.3:cpqNicMibCondition)
         15 - MP            (232.9.1.3:cpqSm2MibCondition) "
```

There is more information in the [HP SIM MIB Kit documentation](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/mibkit.html).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I saw that post after asking the question. That explains the meaning of the array (*but not really how to use it*), despite being buried in the comments of the post. I've been receiving the same management alarms on my G7 servers, which do not have the Agent-less management feature.